# Apache 2.4 with PHP-FPM 5.6 on Centos 6

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, php5

I'm trying to get PHP working over FPM on Centos.

On the FPM side, `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` is pretty much the default values. I'm left it using a TCP port as follows (I may want to change to a file port later for performance, but lets walk before we run):

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

The `php-fpm` service starts without any problems.

So I think my problems are on the Apache side. I added a config file `conf.d/php-fpm.conf` containing the following:

```
# Defining a worker will improve performance
# And in this case, re-use the worker (dependent on support from the fcgi application)
# If you have enough idle workers, this would only improve the performance marginally
<Proxy "fcgi://localhost:9000/" enablereuse=on max=10>
</Proxy>
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
        # Pick one of the following approaches
        # Use the standard TCP socket
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost/:9000"
        # If your version of httpd is 2.4.9 or newer (or has the back-ported feature), you can use the unix domain socket
        #SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/app.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </If>
</FilesMatch>
```

I've set up a test site as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.35:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName centos.local
    ServerAlias www.centos.local

    #ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php)$" "unix:/var/run/myappname.sock|fcgi://localhost/webroot"

    DirectoryIndex index.html

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd24/centos.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd24/centos.access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/centos.local/httpdocs>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/centos.local/httpdocs
        # Allow .htaccess
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

(I'm not sure if the ProxyPassMatch is needed, I seem to get the same result whether I have it or not).

The httpd service starts, and html pages serve fine, but if I try to load a PHP file, I get Service Unavailable in the browser, and the following written to the error log:

```
[Sun Jul 22 21:13:21.813760 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 14621] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/run/myappname.sock (localhost) failed
[Sun Jul 22 21:13:21.814003 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 14621] [client 192.168.1.41:54578] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

Hopefully someone can tell me where I'm going wrong!

**Edit:**

As suggested, I've taken out the ProxyPassMatch. I now get the following error:

```
[Sun Jul 22 23:25:08.066467 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 16319] (13)Permission denied: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (*) failed
[Sun Jul 22 23:25:08.066548 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16319] [client 192.168.1.41:56396] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

It seems to be failing to find the FPM on port 8000, but I can't see anything in any of my config files. What am I missing?

Thanks,

James

Comment: Try to comment the line `ProxyPassMatch  ....`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a TCP socket proxy on `<Proxy "fcgi://localhost:9000/" enablereuse=on max=10>
</Proxy>`

The issue is caused by `SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost/:9000"`

For some reason Apache interprets the slash as a directory separator and defaults to port `8000` for the proxy.

To resolve the issue simply remove the `/` before `:9000`

`SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000"`

Ensure your php-fpm configuration matches:

```
[www]
listen = localhost:9000
listen.allowed_clients=localhost
```

I highly recommend you declare an IP address instead. localhost is kind of a catch-all.

> Since `localhost` can be applied to multiple IP addresses on the
>   webserver, I recommend explicitly specifying an IP, to avoid the
>   proxy being assigned to multiple private IPs or DNS resolution.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> #/etc/hosts
> 127.0.0.1 localhost
> 192.168.1.2 localhost fqdn.example.com
> ```

Below is a suggested Apache virtual host and php-fpm configuration when not using a Unix Domain Socket (UDS).

`9001` is used to not conflict with the default `[www]` php-fpm pool and allow you to create a separate pool configuration.

Ensure your MPM configuration does not conflict with your current configurations.

```
#/etc/httpd/conf.d/01-mpm.conf
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    ServerLimit              100
    StartServers             4
    ThreadLimit              64
    MaxRequestWorkers        100
    MinSpareThreads          25
    MaxSpareThreads          75
    ThreadsPerChild          25
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
    ListenBacklog       511
</IfModule>
```

```
#/etc/httpd/conf.d/999-centos.local.conf
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.35:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName centos.local
    ServerAlias www.centos.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/centos.local/httpdocs

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd24/centos.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd24/centos.access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/centos.local/httpdocs>
        # Allow .htaccess
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
        <Proxy "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/" enablereuse=on max=10>
            ProxySet timeout=1800
        </Proxy>
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
                SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001"
            </If>
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

```
;/etc/php-fpm.d/centos.local.conf
[centos.local]
user=apache
group=apache

listen=127.0.0.1:9001
listen.allowed_clients=127.0.0.1

pm=dynamic
pm.max_children=10
pm.start_servers=2
pm.min_spare_servers=2
pm.max_spare_servers=5

security.limit_extensions=.php
```

---

You can optionally replace the TCP socket configuration in favor of using a UDS.

```
<VirtualHost>
    #...
    <IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
        <Proxy "fcgi://127.0.0.1/" enablereuse=on max=10>
            ProxySet timeout=1800
        </Proxy>
        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            <If "-f %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
                SetHandler proxy:unix:/var/run/unique-domain.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1/
            </If>
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

```
[centos.local]
;...

;listen=127.0.0.1:9001
;listen.allowed_clients=127.0.0.1
listen=/var/run/unique-domain.sock
listen.mode=0660
listen.owner=nobody
listen.group=nobody

;...
```

> Note: 
>   mod_proxy_fcgi UDS support was introduced in Apache 2.4.9 [[sic]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#examples)
>
> You should not use `enablereuse=on` when using UDS and Apache 2.4 < 2.4.11
>   There were issues in Apache prior to 2.4.11 that were not compatible with UDS and connection reuse . [[sic]](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.4.11/CHANGES)
>
> If you experience strange responses or 503 service unavailable errors while using UDS, remove `enablereuse=on max=10` from the `<Proxy "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9001/">`

Comment: Nitpick: You have an extra slash in the last `VirtualHost` block.

Comment: @NisseEngström corrected, thanks. I copy pasted,  just to demonstrate the change to using a `UDS`

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) you've followed shows *three* distinct methods for proxying PHP to php-fpm. They are all mutually exclusive, and you're meant to choose exactly one of them.

I recommend you stick with the *Proxy via handler* approach as in your first code block, and remove the *TCP socket (IP and port) approach* from your second code block. That is, delete the following:

```
    ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php)$" "unix:/var/run/myappname.sock|fcgi://localhost/webroot"
```

It doesn't reference the TCP socket that php-fpm is listening on anyway.

BTW you should also fix the `DirectoryIndex` but that's another issue.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the post with the error I'm getting now.

Comment: @JamesShields Did you forget to set the SELinux boolean?

Comment: It would seem that I did forget to set the SELinux boolean. Most of the tutorials on FPH seem to forget it too. Any hints or pointers on what's needed?

Comment: @JamesShields Or, actually, port number. 8000 isn't allowed by default. See https://serverfault.com/a/566320/126632 for the allowed port numbers and how to add your own.